# Use 'IF' to detect NULL in mysql update query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to give the user the choice to 'overwrite' values in a field in a table or 'add' to the value in the table. The problem is that sometimes the field in the table is null so if the user chooses to 'add' then nothing is updated because mysql is adding null to 10 for instance

I then tried to use the 'IF' statement to detect if the field in the table is null so I can do straight update and if not then I add the new value to the value already in the table.

**Query:**

```
UPDATE
   table1 
   INNER JOIN
      table2 
      ON table1.ID = table2.Table1ID 
SET
   table1.column = 
   (
      IF table1.column = NULL 
   THEN
      table2.column 
   ELSE
      table1.column + table2.column
   )
```

I have an error that says there is a problem with my sql statement. I have tried using 'IS NULL' instead of '= NULL' but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF()` is a function, but you use it like the `CASE` statement. So you get syntax error.
Use it like this:

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.ID = table1.Table1ID 
SET table1.column= IF(table1.column IS NULL, table2.column, table1.column + table2.column)
```

or use a CASE statement:

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.ID = table1.Table1ID 
SET table1.column = CASE 
  WHEN table1.column IS NULL THEN table2.column
  ELSE table1.column + table2.column
END
```

or use COALESCE():

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 
ON table1.ID = table1.Table1ID 
SET table1.column = COALESCE(table1.column, 0) + table2.column
```

Comment: `case` _expression_.

Comment: Worked. Thank you!

Comment: @jarlh yes and no. Here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html it is refrerred as *statement*. Here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 as an *expression*. In most sql oriented web sites it is referred as *statement*. I believe the correct technical term is *expression* but ................

Comment: The MySQL documentation is a bit confusing. A case _expression_ returns a value and can be used in a SELECT etc. A case _statement_ is for conditional execution of code, e.g in a stored procedure or trigger.

Comment: It's not just the MySql documentation. Just google "CASE sql". Most results will have: "The CASE statement...."

Answer (score 1):

You need to use IF ( table1.column is null then ...........)

instead = operator you need IS NULL or IS NOT NULL in case of null checking

Additionally,
 your ON clause seems have a typo .. it should be table1.ID = table2.Table1ID

**Update**

I missed the syntax error completely, so change your set clause to:

```
SET table1.column = (IF table1.column IS NULL, table2.column, table1.column + table2.column )
```

For your reference: https://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-using-if-in-where/

Comment: Thanks Bilal. I changed the = operator to IS NULL but still have the same error. Regarding the typo I typed it wrong here but in the actual code it is correct. The error is "You have an error in your mysql syntax....near 'table1.column IS NULL THEN'....

Comment: ohhh yeah! there is syntax error. I am updating my answer

Comment: Done !! Sorry as I am on cell phone, so missed things in smaller font and also your query was one liner initially. It should work now !! enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

First, nothing compares equal to NULL, not even NULL. Second, yow should use the `IF` *function*:

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.Table1ID
   SET table1.column = IF(table1.column IS NULL, table2.column, table1.column + table2.column)
```

or

```
UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.Table1ID
   SET table1.column = IFNULL(table1.column, 0) + table2.column
```